# What is a B1K1N1 Word™?

Tags: pattern, knowledge, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a B1K1N1 Word™.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| B1K1N1 Words ™ | Not B1K1N1 Words ™ |
| --- | --- |
| ABANDONMENT* | ALTERNATIVELY |
| ABDUCTION† | TAKEN |
| AGENT | FANFARE |
| CENSOR | ALLOW |
| CHAPERONE† | SIBLING |
| CLEANLY | CLEANEST |
| DIJON | KETCHUP |
| GIGABYTE | TYKE |
| LAMBDA | DELTA |
| LOTION | SUNSCREEN |
| MACABRE | DARK |
| PEAS | PLEASE |
| PENSIONABLE‡ | ELDERLY |
| PERSONABLE* | FRIENDLY |
| SKIN | ALBINO |
| SNUB | ACKNOWLEDGE |
| SUBCATEGORY | SUBMARINE |
| SUNBURN | TAN |
| UNBEARABLE† | TOLERATED |
| UNBUCKLE | BUCKLE |
| WHISKY | VODKA |

† Double B1K1N1 words

* Triple B1K1N1 words

‡ Quadruple B1K1N1 words

CSV Version:

```
ABANDONMENT*,ALTERNATIVELY
ABDUCTION†,TAKEN
AGENT,FANFARE
CENSOR,ALLOW
CHAPERONE†,SIBLING
CLEANLY,CLEANEST
DIJON,KETCHUP
GIGABYTE,TYKE
LAMBDA,DELTA
LOTION,SUNSCREEN
MACABRE,DARK
PEAS,PLEASE
PENSIONABLE‡,ELDERLY
PERSONABLE*,FRIENDLY
SKIN,ALBINO
SNUB,ACKNOWLEDGE
SUBCATEGORY,SUBMARINE
SUNBURN,TAN
UNBEARABLE†,TOLERATED
UNBUCKLE,BUCKLE
WHISKY,VODKA
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a B1K1N1 Word™ without relying on the other words.

These are not the only examples of B1K1N1 Words™, many more exist.

**Hint**

> Jamie brings up a good point in the comments. The fact that a bikini is actually two parts might help you see the large hint hidden in plain sight. If not though, here's a list of a couple more B1K1N1 words:
>
> ```
>  ABALONE†
>  AGAPE
>  ARABIC
>  ATONAL
>  BELONG
>  BRISKET
>  CHAPEL
>  COLONS
>  DATABLE
>  DESK
>  EMBOSS
>  LIMB
>  LULLABY
>  OZONE
>  PEAR
>  RUPEE
>  SKINNY
>  TUMBLE
>  ZOMBIE
> ```

**Hint #2**

> I wanted to call them D0M1N0 words, but I would have had to call them K0M1N0 instead if I wanted the title to be a valid `[redacted]`.

**Hint #3**

> With Hint #2 plus the `knowledge` tag, you should be able to get this.

Comment: is whiskey intentionally spelled wrong?

Comment: @thecoder16 Correction to my previous comment: As far as I know, 'WHISKY' (a B1K1N1 word) usually refers to the Scottish drink, while 'WHISKEY' (**also a B1K1N1 word**) usually refers to the Irish drink.

Comment: Is this something to do with `top` and/or `bottom`?

Comment: @JamieBarker I'm not sure what you mean, so likely not.

Comment: In reference to a bikini having a top and a bottom. Never mind  then!

Comment: Been a while and this is still unsolved.  Would you mind adding another hint to push us in the right direction/get this more visible again?

Comment: Is `BIKINI` a **B1K1N1** word?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir No, BIKINI is not a B1K1N1 word

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A B1K1N1 word is a word that

> contains one or more of the [Canadian province/territory abbreviations](http://www.comeexplorecanada.com/abbreviations.php). A double B1K1N1 word contains 2 **non-overlapping** abbreviations (note that `COLONS` isn't counted as a double since `ON` and `NS` overlap), a triple B1K1N1 word contains 3, etc.

Based on the hints, I believe they are called B1K1N1 words because

> The string "B1K 1N1" is a [Canadian postal code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_Canada) (specifically for [Grand Mira North](http://postal-code-lookup.com/canada/nova-scotia/grand-mira-north-postal-codes/B1K-1N1)), which is another way to reference regions of Canada. Not every combination of letters and numbers is used. "D0M 1N0" doesn't exist ("D" isn't used), but "K0M 1N0" does. Also, a bikini is a two-piece bathing suit, and province abbreviations have two letters.

Comment: Nice job! Thanks for finally closing this :)

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for finally solving this. Why are these words called B1K1N1 words?

Comment: @MorganG: Thanks for the challenge! I really racked my brain on that one.

Answer (score 4):

This seems almost too obvious...

A B1K1N1 word is

> A word where alternate letters can be substituted with numbers, according to the following rule:
>  1 = I or L, 2 = Z, 3 = E, 4 = A, 5 = S, 6 = H or U, 7 = Y or T, 8 = B, 9 = R, 0 = O

So for example:

> `AGENT => 4G3N7`
>  `GIGABYTE => G1G4B7T3`
>  `SUBCATEGORY => 5U8C4T3G0R7`
>  `WHISKY => W6I5K7`
>  `BIKINI => B1K1N1`

Comment: Good attempt @F1Krazy. How about substituting 'H' or 'U' ... or for that matter ..it requires full set of numbers for 26 alphabets...I think..:-)

Comment: now you can write TYKE in this form too

Comment: @ffao I thought this solution was too obvious...

Comment: Since SUBCATEGORY, MACABRE and LOTION are B1K1N1 words, wouldn't that approach also make SUBMARINE a B1K1N1 word?